# Were Poltergist and E.T. filmed in the same neighborhood?

Tags: film-location, poltergeist, et-the-extra-terrestrial

Were the two 1982 Spielberg movies *E.T.* and *Poltergeist* filmed in the same neighborhood? They were both filmed in tract housing developments during the same year. Were they filmed in the same place in succession?

Comment: Funny, I've wondered the same thing. As a kid I always wanted to buy a house like the one in E.T.

Comment: The exterior of the Poltergeist house was actually in Simi Valley (I lived in Simi from 1977-1990 and my friends and I used to ride our bikes by it frequently to "scare" ourselves in the summer of '82!)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**No, they are not the same place.**

According to [this site](http://www.fast-rewind.com/locations_polter.htm), Poltergeist was filmed in Agoura Hills.

[image]

[Another page on the same site](http://www.fast-rewind.com/locations_et.htm) indicates that the street where they take off on the bike (I assume that's the one you're thinking of) is filmed in Granada Hills.

[image]

As a semi-related piece of trivia I found on that same site, in the Charlie's Angel's remake starring Drew Barrymore, there's a scene where she rolls into the villain's backyard, and the house is the same one she and Eliot lived in in E.T.